# Как добавить картинку сердечка к кнопке?

Tags: css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка сердечка импортирована из `figma` и имеет прозрачный фон. При добавлении к ней белого фона виден белый зазор, как это исправить?

Comment: Ну, просто поверх правого края кнопки накладываете картинку и всё - в чём проблема?

Comment: собственно это и есть красная кнопка с сердечком сбоку, если добавлять картинку поверх кнопки то  она просто сливается с кнопкой, потому что у нее фон прозрачный, а если добавить белый фон то виден белый зазор между сердечком и кнопкой

Comment: @Marro, посмотрите, я сделал пример - никакого зазора. Просто позиционирование и размеры надо подогнать, и всё.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 50px;
  background-color: #e20613;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
img {
  position: relative;
  top: 11px;
  left: -11px;
  height: 31px;
}
```

```html
<button>Сделать доброе дело</button><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iY6xh.jpg" alt="" />
```